# How to improve the quality of the `concorde` TSP solver? Am I misusing it?

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to use the `concorde` TSP solver in a file using the following format:

```
NAME : p5
COMMENT : Nada
TYPE : TSP
DIMENSION : 20
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
0 0.329733 0.67714
1 0.823944 0.035369
2 0.002488 0.866692
3 0.241964 0.671822
4 0.98876 0.134457
5 0.879147 0.457779
6 0.021017 0.271951
7 0.221737 0.367143
8 0.549802 0.523319
9 0.363839 0.22359
10 0.696631 0.495935
11 0.279072 0.100501
12 0.660156 0.860675
13 0.251769 0.029172
14 0.32112 0.207704
15 0.821433 0.507387
16 0.095411 0.953448
17 0.115897 0.269363
18 0.704484 0.411328
19 0.705198 0.795917
```

Since I couldn't find a guide about the format, I just modified a sample file I downloaded. I am running the following command:

```
concorde myFile.tsp
```

It quickly (~45ms) outputs the solution as a .sol file, which results in something like that:

```
20
0 10 19 8 12 15 5 4 18 1 
9 17 6 11 7 13 14 3 2 16
```

Graphing, I get:

[image]

Which, by visual inspection, is too far from an ideal solution. Thus,

1. Am I doing something wrong with the file format or command?
2. If not, considering how fast it computed the solution, can I prompt it to spend more time looking for better solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EUC_2D` is the *rounded* L2 norm.  That is, the distance between two points is taken to be their Euclidean distance rounded to the nearest integer.  Your points are all going to be at distances 0 or 1 to one another and Concorde is going to generate a daft tour like the one you drew.

Scale your problem up until the rounding stops making a difference.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem. Thank you very much!